# Please reopen "Does open sourcing your work help you?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

[Does open sourcing your work help you?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/193893/3965) was originally worded in a polling, discussion-inducing way ("Have you ever", "work of yours", "Is it a world of selfishness"), but is not fundamentally a polling, discussion-inducing question.  I edited to fix the language, and I hope people will join me in voting to reopen.

Comment: as one of close-voters of [original version](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/193893/1 "'Have you ever gotten a sense of blah blah'") I confirm that your revision made it worth re-open to me (voted accordingly)

Comment: I cast a reopen vote.

Comment: A significant edit on a closed question enters it into the re-open queue automatically, so it gets almost immediate attention from re-open voters. You also have the option of dropping the question in chat and asking people to take a look and obviously you can always flag for moderation attention (if no-one's in chat). Let's not make a habit of posting a Meta question until after we tried everything else, because frankly in most cases it isn't worth the trouble (which in this case was mostly yours). On clear cut cases like this when there's no obvious reason for a discussion, Meta is overkill.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, @Yannis, but I can't usually tell beforehand if other people will see it as clear cut.  In my mind, if it was clear cut, closers would have done the same edit instead of closing.  I will try chat next time, though.

Comment: My point here is don't waste your time with Meta until you actually need to. Dropping a question in chat and posting a single "Hey, does this look good for re-opening?" message is usually enough and it's much faster than typing a Meta question. Even if no one's around at the time, someone will pick up on your message soon enough. If the question isn't re-opened after a few hours, go ahead and post on Meta. Nothing wrong with posting on Meta immediately, but in this case (for example) the question became obsolete in minutes.